# How to Check if discord is running?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add discord rich presence in my game(made using Unity 2022.1, on Windows 10), but as many may know, trying to use rich presence when discord isn't open crashes the game/editor and opens discord.

My work around this has been using **System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()** to check if discord is open and running(by checking each returned value and seeing if they're equal to "System.Diagnostics.Process (Discord)")

The issue is, when within the editor(On windows) it works fine, but outside of the editor, still on Windows, it doesn't seem to, and I don't know why.(I've tested without that check, and discord's rich presence doesn't seem to be the cause of the issue)

How do I fix this? Is there an alternative way to check if discord is running?

Answer (score 1):

I think it solves this problem. You should check the discord list process.

```cs
if (Process.GetProcessesByName("Discord").Length > 0)
{
    Debug.Log("Discord is Running..");
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("Discord doesn't Running...");
}
```

Comment: sadly no, this results in the same: work in the editor, but not on the build

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little late, but still...

Discord Game SDK requires the client to be running when using the standard flags in the class constructor. To remove this dependency, you can use `Discord.CreateFlags.NoRequireDiscord` instead of `Discord.CreateFlags.Default`

Don't forget to check for NullRef because if the client is not running and you try to call the constructor, you won't get anything.

There is another answer to finding the Discord process... In conjunction with my answer, you can simply not enable Discord Rich Presence if the client is not running, as there is a pitfall: I get an exception somewhere on the ctor statement inside the library (this is a CIL language statement).

So it's better to immediately check for a running client in the operating system processes and if it's not there, just don't initialize the library.

For more information, you can take a closer look here:

https://discord.com/developers/docs/game-sdk/discord#discord